fetching and iterating of multipolygon data is taking very long time to execute
I have 3 models fire, earthquakes and flood hazards. The fire hazards has 450 plus rows containing 3 columns id, date and geometry(having data in format 0106000020E61......). The fire hazards is taking very long time (in hours) to fetch and return the data because of the geometry column.
To make it efficient I'm now fetching the rows within 3 km for which it fetches only 30-40 rows out of 450 plus rows but still it takes minutes to fetch, load, iterate and return.
How to optimize my code and make it return in fractions of seconds? The code is in python django
def fetch_hazards_layers(bounds, zoom):
from .models import EarthquakeHazards
from .models import FireHazards
from .models import FloodHazards
# from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
# from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
# from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
print('inside fetch_hazards_layers_test ')
min_lat = bounds['south']
min_lng = bounds['west']
max_lat = bounds['north']
max_lng = bounds['east']

center_lat = (min_lat + max_lat) / 2
center_lng = (min_lng + max_lng) / 2
center_point = Point(center_lng, center_lat, srid=4326)

buffer_distance = 3  # distance in km
buffer = center_point.buffer(buffer_distance / 111.32)

# viewport = Polygon.from_bbox((min_lng, min_lat, max_lng, max_lat))

hazards_geom = []
count = 0
batch_size = 5

def fetch_hazards_in_batches(hazards_queryset, hazard_type):
    nonlocal count
    hazard_ids = list(hazards_queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))
    for start in range(0, len(hazard_ids), batch_size):
        end = start + batch_size
        batch_ids = hazard_ids[start:end]
        hazard_batch = hazards_queryset.filter(id__in=batch_ids).only('geom').iterator()
        for hazard in hazard_batch:
            hazards_geom.append({'type': hazard_type, 'geometry': hazard.geom.geojson})
            count += 1

flood_hazards = FloodHazards.objects.filter(geom__intersects=buffer)
fire_hazards = FireHazards.objects.filter(geom__intersects=buffer)
earthquake_hazards = EarthquakeHazards.objects.filter(geom__intersects=buffer)

fetch_hazards_in_batches(flood_hazards, 'Flood')
fetch_hazards_in_batches(fire_hazards, 'Fire')
fetch_hazards_in_batches(earthquake_hazards, 'Earthquake')

To make it working I tried to reduce the distance from 3 km to 100/500 meters but in that case, this line fire_hazards = FireHazards.objects.filter(geom__intersects=buffer) is not able to fetch all the times. i,e. sometimes it fetches properly but sometimes it does not fetch even a single row for the same bound area.
Can someone please help me where I can fetch within 3 km where it takes fraction of seconds to fetch, load, iterate and return.
I don't mind bringing the buffer distance to 100 meters but in that case it should fetch the rows consistently all the time and also within fractions of seconds.
